# How to implement redirect to other page after some long process in Page_Load?

Tags: asp.net, async-await, asp.net-4.5

Hello I would like to make redirection to other page after some process on server side in Page_Load event with Asp Net 4.5 syntax (ASYNC and TASK keywords).

I fount out this way something like this to start backed task (but this is possible in old asp .net as well):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask.aspx 
but as I remember if I will change content on page I can't make redirection with Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out how to do it I need use handler and call in in js.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/how-to-create-an-asynchronous-http-handler-in-asp.net-4.5.htm

http://forums.asp.net/t/1600144.aspx/1